# Pegar a stream do device selecionado

Tags: javascript, html5

Preciso pegar a stream de áudio reproduzida no fone/alto-falantes do usuário e estou encontrando um problema na hora de pegar a stream do device selecionado. Em suma é o seguinte: O fone acaba tendo o mesmo id do microfone 'Default' e o retorno de 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia' mesmo enviando o device acaba se tornando o retorno do microfone.

```
this.start = function () {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    })
    .then(function (objStream) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (objDevices) {
            var objAudio = objDevices.find(function (objDevice) {
                return objDevice.kind == "audiooutput";
            });

            objStream.getTracks().forEach(function (objMidiaAudio) {
                objMidiaAudio.stop();
            });

            if (objAudio) {
                return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    audio: objAudio
                });
            }

            return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: true
            });
        })
    .then(function (objStream) {
        new Promise(function () {
            var audio = objStream.getAudioTracks()[0];
```

Isso seria o trecho de código onde estou com problema, a variável objAudio, possuí o fone, mas quando retorno ao 'then' o objStream possuí o microfone. Alguma sugestão de como contornar esse problema?